# Java JDBC - update statement failing to update and no exception thrown

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-update

I've created a small SWING application that is connected to MySQL workbench. I'm trying to write the code for the jbutton that when pressed it updates the table inside the database. I went through all the Q&As here on StackOverflow but the query is still failing to perform an update inside the database. I tried to debug the code by putting some print statements and I noticed that the prepared statement doesn't receive the update when a certain cell is modified. Yet, there is no exception thrown. How can I tackle this?

```
JButton update_Button = new JButton("UPDATE ");
                update_Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        Connection connection = null;   
                        
                        int selectIndex = table_1.getSelectedRow();
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(selectIndex, 0).toString());
                                                                        
                        try {
                            
                            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/librarydatabase", "root", "Connection");  
                            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                            String sql = "UPDATE book SET author = ?, title = ?,subject = ?, publisher = ?, language = ? WHERE bookID = ?";
                            PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);                                                                                     
                            statement.setString(1, author_TextField.getText());
                            statement.setString(2, title_TextField.getText());
                            statement.setString(3, subject_ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            statement.setString(4, publisher_ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            statement.setString(5, language_ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            statement.setInt(6, id);
                                                                                                                                                        
                            statement.execute();    
                            connection.commit();
                            
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The book has been updated successfully");
                            
                            statement.close();
                            connection.close();
                            
                    
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(Throwable e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: If you feel comfortable, please consider including your database

Comment: check your server logs there might be some error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
statement.executeUpdate();
```

instead of

```
statement.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and I understand that it's better you can use *executeUpdate* method. And it's a good practice if you can create different class for database connection don't create all methods and database connection in same class.

```
        Connection conn;
        conn = DbConnect.connect();

        int colum;
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        String data = table.getValueAt(row, 2).toString();
        System.out.println(data);

        try {
            String sql = "UPDATE book SET author = ?, title = ?,subject = ?, publisher = ?, language = ? WHERE id = ?";
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
            pst.setString(2, table.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
            pst.setString(3, table.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
            pst.setString(4, table.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
            pst.setString(5, table.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
            pst.setString(6, table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            int a = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (a > 0) {
                System.out.println("Successfully update");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Faild to update");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:
Successfully update

Comment: Thanks Kanishka. I was following a tutorial and it didn't create different classes for each button, I will follow your suggestion. Anyway I tried your code, it does work, but it still doesn't update the database, which is where my issue is.

Comment: I think you have to mention the database in your code If you are using mysql `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` before getConnection If you are using Oracle then Class.forName(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)